# Button to Swap Image Set

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, button, swap

I am attempting to implement a script that will fade in a new set of images, replacing an old set, upon a click event on a button that will be an image or piece of text. To get an idea of what I am looking to replicate (in flash, unfortunately), see the "teaching" section of http://seanjustice.com/.

I found this [jfiddle from another topic on stackoverflow](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/H8z2G/2/), but I wasn't sure how to use a button and mouse click to replace the set of images instead of using just a simple fade upon hover effect.

So can anyone help me out with suggestions? **How do I use a button that will trigger a swap of images?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the jsfiddle you provided you could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/H8z2G/41/

```
$('.fadein').each(function() {

    var std = $(this).attr("src");
    var hover = std.replace("text=1", "text=2");
    $(this).wrap('<div />').clone().insertAfter(this).attr('src', hover).removeClass('fadein').siblings().css({
        position:'absolute'
    });

    $('#swapper').click(function() {
        $('.fadein').stop().fadeTo(600, 0);
    });
});​
```

Sorry, here's the markup:

```
<img class="fadein" src="http://dummyimage.com/180x100/000/fff&text=1" alt="" />
<img class="fadein" src="http://dummyimage.com/180x100/cf5/fff&text=1" alt="" />
<img class="fadein" src="http://dummyimage.com/180x100/f0f/fff&text=1" alt="" />

<a href="#" id="swapper">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: You will need to change hover around, let's say your images were named 
myimagev1.jpg, myimagev2.jpg, unrelatedimagev1.jpg, and unrelatedimagev2.jpg you could change it to var hover = std.replace("v1.jpg", "v2.jpg");

Comment: Brandon, how do I incorporate this into my code? I did the normal thing where you put the javascript in the head and the images in the html (obviously) but when I click on the click here button, nothing swaps. I then put them inside a new div with class 'imageswapping' and made the zindex high enough, and it still didnt do anything. What could I be missing?  Do I need to somehow select the fadein class differently since its in a div with a different class?

Comment: Okay so I got the code to work:


`$(document).ready(function(){
$('.fadein').each(function() {
    
    var std = $(this).attr("src");
    var hover = std.replace("2010-1_csi.jpg", "2010-2_csi.jpg");
    $(this).wrap('<div />').clone().insertAfter(this).attr('src', hover).removeClass('.fadein').siblings().css({
        position:'absolute'
    });
    
    $('#swapper').click(function() {
        $('.fadein').stop().fadeTo(600, 0);
    });
});
});`
But then the code doesn't work correctly-- When I click on the "Click Here" link, the images fade to the next set, but then _that_ set disapppears